# Use powershell on remote machine for Edge Version

Tags: powershell

I have a script that returns Version numbers for 3rd Party software running on our Domain. Java, chrome, etc to ensure we are up to date. 
This is all working OK.

However, I am trying to use:

```
Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | select-object Version
```

within a remote Powershell session or 'invoke-command' but it is returning no results,

the command works fine if locally, and also when RDP'd onto the remote machine.

How can i use this cmdlet remotely to check Edge is version compliant?

Many Thanks.

EDIT:

```
    import-module activedirectory


    $workstations = Get-ADComputer -Filter "OperatingSystem -like 'Windows 10 *'" -Property * | select name -ExpandProperty Name


    foreach ($workstation in $workstations)
{

$session = New-PSSession -Computername $workstation 


$resultofsession = Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock{




$Path="HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*"       
$path2 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\"

$java = Get-ItemProperty $Path | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | where displayname -like "java*"
$chrome =  Get-ItemProperty $path | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | where displayname -ceq "Google Chrome"
$adobe = Get-ItemProperty $path | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion | where displayname -ceq "Adobe Acrobat Reader DC"
$edge = Get-AppxPackage -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | select-object Version
$ie = get-itemProperty $path2 

$Object = New-Object PSObject -property @{

'chrome'        = "CHROME: " + $chrome.displayversion + ","
'edge'          = "EDGE: " + $edge + ","
'ie'            = "IE: " + $ie.svcVersion + ","
'java'          = "JAVA: " + $java.Displayversion + ","
'adobe'         = "ADOBE: " + $adobe.displayversion + ","
'hostname'      = hostname

}

Write-output $object 

}

remove-pssession $session

write-output $resultofsession | format-table -HideTableHeaders -autosize -force | Out-File "C:\web\Version.txt" -append

}
```

Comment: What Windows 10 build number does the remote machine have? It seems on builds earlier than 10240 you could try `-Name *Edge*` or `-Name *Spartan*`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the build number is 17134. The thing is, the command works perfectly fine when run directly from the machine,  just not in the remote ps session

Comment: Then your issue is the implementation of the session - not the command. You should include your entire invoke-command statement in the question.

Comment: Full script added as requested :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Get-AppxPackage` will return only information for the current users profile (in this case, the account running the script). You likely need to add the `-AllUsers` switch, but note this will return a result for each user logged in (and they *may* have different versions). You can use the `-user` parameter to specify a specific user.

AppX packages are only updated for the user profile when they log in, hence why different users *can* have different versions of an app on the same workstation. Assuming everything works as expected, the app *should* be updated when the user next logs in.

Try the following to return the version number for each user ID:

```
$edge = Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers -Name Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge | select-object @{N="User"; E={$_.packageUserInformation.UserSecurityId.Username}},Version
```

Example output:

```
User     Version
----     -------
test     42.17127.1.0
S-1-5-18 44.17763.1.0
jacob    44.18252.1000.0
```

Comment: That worked absolutely perfectly, Thank you Jacob :) I would Up-Vote your reply but i lack sufficient reputation.